# How to deal with repeatedly measured independent variables?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, panel-data, random-effects-model

I have data from a clinical trial from a bunch of participants followed over a year.

These participants underwent at month 0, 6 and 12, a battery of cognitive tests. The scores in these tests are the dependent variables to be predicted. As predictors we have severals variables such as steps, sleep quality, heart rate etc as registered by their fitbits.

I wanted to fit a model for each cognitive test and see how well the predictors can predict their values over time. I was thinking to use a multivariate random coefficient model using the nmle R package, but I am not sure for example how to handle the fact that the resolution of the cognitive scores to be predicted is just 3 points over a year, while the predictors are measured every minute or even every second. Even if I summarize these value per day (taking the mean for example) still should I use all the days in the model (365 days) or only the three days (month 0, 6 and 12) where the cognitive tests where performed?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know of any great way to model across multiple time scales like this. You could impute linear values for the predictors in between the tests, but that sounds bad. More likely what is needed is a reformatting of the Fitbit data. For example sum the Fitbit measures as average activity per day. Maybe use the 0th month for the first measure, the 1-6th for the second cognitive tests, and the 7th-12th for the final cognitive test. This also might serve you better for interpretability.